# $(...).tagit is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tag-it

i got an issue with tagit plugin, I can't use it I always got the error `$(...).tagit is not a function`. Jquery and Jquery Ui are included in my footer and tagit is included in the body. I have jquery ui 1.12.0 min and jquery 2.2.4 min. 
So if anyone already got this error with this plugin or any other plugin I could use some help. Thanks

I have my main page which include the javascript so:

```
<ul id="tags">
    <!-- Existing list items will be pre-added to the tags -->
    <li>Tags</li>
</ul>
<script src="<?php echo asset_url("js/ActiviteComplet.js");?>" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And ActiviteComplet.js:

```
window.addEventListener('load', initEventHandler, false);

function initEventHandler()
{
    var availableTags = [
        "testa",
        "btest"
    ];
    $("#tags").tagit({
        autocomplete: {delay: 0, minLength: 2, source: availableTags}
    });
}
```

And finally everything else is included in my footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo asset_url("js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo asset_url("js/jquery-ui.min.js"); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo asset_url("js/bootstrap.min.js"); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo asset_url("js/tag-it.js");?>" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Console error output:

```
ActiviteComplet.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tagit is not a functioninitEventHandler @ ActiviteComplet.js:9
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are using the plugin ?

Comment: We need to see code.

Comment: are you calling this function before plugin is loaded?

Comment: Please add code snippet, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Because `$(...)` looks more like an empty cup.

Comment: I added more code so now instead of downvote are you ready to help me ?

Comment: Please add your browser console output as well. Do you see any error there?

Comment: try look at your source code in browser and navigate to plugin path to see if the plugin is really included in your page

Comment: The plugin is only included in the footer I'm sure of it

Answer (score 4):

Check a few things:

1. jQuery is included
2. Tagit library is included
3. jQuery is included before Tagit plugin
4. jQuery is not included more than once

**EDIT**
jQuery UI is also required as it's a dependency of tagit as pointed out by @Bob Kaufman.

Comment: 1.5 jQuery-ui is included

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @BobKaufman :) I have updated the answer.